# Is it possible to do this on the Android and iPhone? (for mobile developers)

Tags: iphone, android, url, browser, mobile

Embed a browser inside the application.
When the user navigates to a desired page, he pushes a button to "set" this page.

Now, the application gets the URL of this page!

How hard is this to do on the Android and iPhone?

Answer (score 3):

The iPhone has the UIWebView class

see [Here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

I'm not sure about Android though.

Answer (score 3):

On Android, yes it's possible. See [WebView#getUrl](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#getUrl()).

Answer (score 1):

You can try 'WebView' in android.
Refer to [WebView](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html).

Answer (score 0):

You may use this.

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(baseUrl-add some fake url here, data, mimeType, encoding, failUrl-add some fake url here);
```